# Spring Rest Template Client : Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused

Tags: java, android, json, spring, rest

This my Android Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_rest);

         pdialog=new ProgressDialog(this);

         query = getIntent().getExtras().getString("query");
         if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(query))
               new GetRestTask().execute(query);

}

private class GetRestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ObjectExchanged>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pdialog.setCancelable(true);
        pdialog.setMessage("Sending ....");
        pdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ObjectExchanged doInBackground(String... request) {
        Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
      //   vars.put("query", ClientRestActivity.this.query);

        if(request != null && request.length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                return ( getRestTemplate()).getForObject(URL, ObjectExchanged.class,query );

            }

            catch (RestClientException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ObjectExchanged result) {

        if(result == null )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non trouvé ou erreur", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            pdialog.dismiss();          
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowResults.class);

            intent.putExtra("list_uri", result.response);
            pdialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}


private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    if(restTemplate == null)
    {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
        List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> listHttpMessageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
        listHttpMessageConverters.add(jsonConverter);
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(listHttpMessageConverters);
    }
    return restTemplate;
}
```

And this is my Servelet in server Side

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String query= request.getParameter("query");

    /*System.out.println(query);
    PrintWriter out2 = response.getWriter();
    out2.println("<LI> Parametre 1: " + query); 
    */

    System.out.println(query);
    PrintWriter out2 = response.getWriter();

    out2.println("done ");

    ArrayList<URI> uris= new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Scanner s= new Scanner(new File ("urls.txt"));
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            uris.add(new URI(s.nextLine()));

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    ObjectExchanged objectExchanged = new ObjectExchanged(query,uris);


    if (objectExchanged.equals(null)) {
        System.out.println("null");
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("not null");

    Writer out =response.getWriter();
    String repJson = new Gson().toJson(objectExchanged);
    System.out.println(repJson);
    out.write(repJson);
}
```

I try to run this on my own device

This is the log

```
06-17 21:36:23.720: W/System.err(3010): org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused
06-17 21:36:23.720: W/System.err(3010):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:456)
06-17 21:36:23.720: W/System.err(3010):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:404)
06-17 21:36:23.720: W/System.err(3010):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:202)
06-17 21:36:23.720: W/System.err(3010):     at com.pfe.client.webservice.ClientRestActivity$GetRestTask.doInBackground(ClientRestActivity.java:74)
06-17 21:36:23.720: W/System.err(3010):     at com.pfe.client.webservice.ClientRestActivity$GetRestTask.doInBackground(ClientRestActivity.java:1)
06-17 21:36:23.720: W/System.err(3010):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-17 21:36:23.720: W/System.err(3010):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:3        06)
06-17 21:36:23.720: W/System.err(3010):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-17 21:36:23.720: W/System.err(3010):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010): Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:82)
06-17 21:36:23.730: W/System.err(3010):     at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:52)
06-17 21:36:23.740: W/System.err(3010):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:441)
06-17 21:36:23.740: W/System.err(3010):     ... 10 more
06-17 21:36:23.740: W/System.err(3010): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:8080 - Connection refused
06-17 21:36:23.740: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
06-17 21:36:23.740: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
06-17 21:36:23.750: W/System.err(3010):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
06-17 21:36:23.750: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-17 21:36:23.750: W/System.err(3010):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
06-17 21:36:23.750: W/System.err(3010):     ... 19 more
```

Comment: Do you have a server started on your Android device?

Comment: no! how can I check this ?

Comment: It would be good if you improved your question. What you want to achieve? Why are you connecting to localhost:8080 from Android device?

Comment: @MaciejGórski I want to send a String to the server and receiving an object as response ; I try to use Spring Rest Template

So my Android device is the client and the server is my own PC

Answer (score 5):

localhost redirects calls by your router back to 127.0.0.1, which is the same device. So unless your server is on the phone, this will cause a crash. If you have a server that is connected to the same router network(wifi or lan) as your phone, then get the local IP of the server from your router or server and replace localhost with it.

Note: phone and server must be connected to the same router

Comment: For others who have seen this response, given at the time this was not marked as a solution, this suggestion worked in my case. When testing on a real device, ensure your WS is not localhost (where you web service is sitting on a physical server somwhere).